# Cannot bind to webservice: java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I am trying to bind to an existing legacy webservice that is running in a test environment hosted on a JBoss server but Spring cannot create the bean due to the below exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:675)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.getPortStub(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:413)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:337)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.java:42)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Exception
        at uk.co.example.UserException
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement uk.co.example.ObjectFactory.createUserException(uk.co.example.UserException)
        at uk.co.example.ObjectFactory

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:140)
```

I'm binding to the webservice via Spring xml:

```
<bean id="auth1" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="uk.co.example.Authentication" />
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://testdomain.co.uk:30001/services/authentication?wsdl" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://example.co.uk/" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="AuthenticationWebServiceService" />
    <property name="portName" value="AuthenticationPort" />
    <property name="maintainSession" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My UserException simply extends java.lang.Exception:

```
public class UserException extends Exception
{

}
```

So my webservice contains a method that declares a throw of UserException. UserException extends java.lang.Exception which contains a reference to StackTraceElement which doesn't have a no-arg constructor. Hence the JAXB exception. That much I've picked up from some other posts on this matter.

What I don't understand is: why this particular webservice and this particular exception class? And of course, how I correct this?

My webservice throws numerous other exceptions (most appear to extend java.lang.Exception). Another webservice (which doesn't throw UserException, but throws other bespoke Exception subclasses) that runs in the same JBoss server works fine. The 2 different sets of webservices have different client jars.

I've simply created an Eclipse Maven project, pulled in the Spring test and web jars (v3.1.0), junit and log4j. The 2 client jars (pre-existing as part of the legacy build) are also on the classpath. I've created a Junit that autowires the proxy bean as the Authentication interface and call an authenticateUser() method on it.

Because it's legacy code, I can't change anything in the running webservice, or the generated client jars.

Any suggestions?

I'll admit to been a bit of a novice when it comes to webservices and also how our legacy code is built and deployed, so don't be afraid to ask anything that you think might be too obvious!

Comment: Why can't you change the client jars?

Comment: I had the same problem on JDK 1.7 when JAXWS interface and METRO 2.0 implementation where mistakenly included into war file by IDE(NetBeans). After cleaning up the project the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the client or the server code, you could still write your own client that extends the existing client and try to [add a custom JAXB binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) there.